Grease Pencil white border
So i'm drawing in greace pencil for the first time. Now i'm adding a background for my character that i just drawed. But there appears this white strange pixels around the character.

Is there any way i can prevent these pixels from appearing?

ok i just found a solution if anyone is faceing the same problem. it seems to be important, that the background is an "image as a plane" therefor you need to activate the add on, images as planes.
